# Goroutine is causing segmentation fault in EKS Pod

Tags: go, nullpointerexception, segmentation-fault, amazon-eks, goroutine

```
func (l *LS) GetRCDetails(ctx *common.Context, rcRequest vm.RCRequest) (vm.RCResponseData, base.VError) {
    defer common.StartSegment(ctx, "GetRCDetails").End()
    var rcResponse vm.RCResponse
    filter := bson.M{"reg_no": rcRequest.RCNumber}

    err := l.Mongo.Client.Collection(RCDataCollection).FindOne(ctx.Ctx, filter).Decode(&rcResponse.Data)
    ctx.Logger.Infof("error in decode :: %v", err)
    //to update existing vehicle data for additional fields
    if err == nil && rcResponse.Data.RegNo != "" && rcResponse.Data.Engine != "" {
        return rcResponse.Data, nil
    }
    ctx.Logger.Infof("Calling Notification service to get RC for RegNo:%s", rcRequest.RCNumber)
    _, rcResponse, err = l.notificationService.GetRCResponse(ctx, rcRequest)
    ctx.Logger.Infof("Received RC response from Notification service for RegNo:%s", rcRequest.RCNumber)
    if err != nil || rcResponse.Message != "" {
        verror := base.NewVahakError(http.StatusBadRequest, errors.New(rcResponse.Message)).DoNotSentryInstance()
        return rcResponse.Data, verror
    }
    rcResponse.Data.CreatedAt = time.Now().UTC()
    rcResponse.Data.UpdatedAt = time.Now().UTC()
    l.Mongo.Save(ctx, RCDataCollection, rcResponse.Data)
    return rcResponse.Data, nil

}
```

l.Mongo.Client.Collection(RCDataCollection).FindOne(ctx.Ctx, filter).Decode(&rcResponse.Data)
This above line is part of my function which is causing segmentation fault when I am running in goroutine in my pod of EKS, but same function is running fine when I calling it outside of the goroutine.

Note : I tried printing every thing but none of the variables used in above code is nil.
but still I am getting error as

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x13905b6]
```

But that error is not coming when I am calling separately outside of the goroutine.

What could be the possible issue with go routine?

Comment: What does the rest of the goroutine look like? Where are those variables defined?

Comment: @J.Titus This groutine is called inside another function and all the variables which are used are passed to that gorutine function.
This rcResponse is declared in another package, but it is accessible, I tried to add debug print statement and it is working.

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code as a snippet?

Comment: @meshkati I added code snippet which is being called from goroutine

Comment: After more debug what I found that even though I am trying to execute l.Mongo.Client.ListCollectionNames(context.TODO(), bson.D{}) , I am getting same error.
but my l.Mongo.Client is not null